# Deleting Row PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've been following this tutorial 
[Best way to delete mysql rows from html page - delete link and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137268/best-way-to-delete-mysql-rows-from-html-page-delete-link-and-php)

But I got stuck, my rows wouldn't delete.
Please help

```
// My Viewing dish Page
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dish");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>DishID</th>
<th>DishName</th>
<th>DishPrice</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DishID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DishName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DishPrice'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['DishID'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>


//Delete Page

<?php

require_once("database.php");


/* 
 DELETE.PHP
 Deletes a specific entry from the 'players' table
*/


 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['DishID']) && is_numeric($_GET['DishID']))
 {
 // get id value
 $DishID = $_GET['DishID'];

 // delete the entry
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM dish WHERE DishID =$DishID} ")
 or die(mysql_error());


 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: admin_modifydishes.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
echo "doesn'twork";
 }

?>
```

I believe it is something to do with $DishID = $_GET['DishID'];. But I cannot get around it, please help.

Comment: Why there is "}" at end of delete query?

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM dish WHERE DishID =$DishID} ")` is wrong. Try removing the `}`

Comment: Shouldn't "WHERE DishID =$DishID}" be "WHERE DishID = {$DishID}"

Comment: Your form is supplying `?id=` but you are querying against `$_GET['DishId']` . Use `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Shouldn't OP be receiving a MySQL error here? The contents would be interesting.

Comment: Warning: The `mysql_xx()` functions are **deprecated**. They are obsolete and insecure. You are strongly advised to switch your code to use the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy

The URL is to delete is: `delete.php?id=your-id`

To get the `id` parameter, you need to use `$_GET['id']`, **not** `$_GET['DishID']`.

Also, your delete query is a bit wrong. Try replacing it with:

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `dish` WHERE `DishID`={$DishID}");
```

Comment: Please reference the fact that the delete statement is wrong as well.

Comment: Yes, i have changed the values for it, but it's still not working.

Comment: Ahhh Yes, I have also changed the (isset($_GET['id']).. thanks very much!!

Comment: You can mark an answer as correct by pressing the big outlined "V" left of an answer. This allows future users with the same question to find this answer more easily and will make us answer your questions faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM dish WHERE DishID =$DishID} ")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

should be

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM dish WHERE DishID =$DishID")
```

and

```
$_GET['DishID']
```

Should be

```
$_GET['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that you're creating a world of pain for yourself here, unless you are sanitising the input somewhere.

Using SQL like this leaves you wide open to an SQL injection attack. If its possible, as well as sanitisation you should look at the PDO modules.

You should also take a look at http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases